# Problem with rebooting Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 32-bit

Tags: cinnamon, busybox, reboot

I was browsing on FireFox in Linux mint 18 cinnamon and I couldn't log in my google account, so I closed the browser, but after I tried to turn it back on, it showed me a notification:

> *"Firefox is already running, but it is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system."*

Firstly I restarted it, it worked fine for a while, but I still couldn't log in the google account, so I closed the browser again and when I tried to open the browser, the same notification appeared. I logged out my profile, but then was written on the screen (right after I wrote the Security key):

> BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

I wrote `exit` and this is what appeared:

> (initramfs) exit /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced. Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
>
> /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCOSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY (i.e., without -a or -p options) fsck exited with status code 4 The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root requires a manual fsck**

Does anyone know, why this occured and how to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

You have encountered a serious harddrive problem.

Boot from install media and save your data to another disk - ASAP